# Clear a cloned fieldset with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, list

I cloned a fieldset and now I need to clear the value of the cloned fieldset. How can I do this with jquery?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EwcjE/3/)

html

```
<form action="#" method="POST" name="list" >

<!-- here other data are filled out  -->

        <ul id="list">
            <li class="wishlist_item">

              <fieldset class="fields">


                <label for="title">title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" value="title A" />

            </fieldset>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

js

```
$("#list").append($('ul#list li:first').clone()).html();
$('ul#list li:last').find('input:item').val('');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$('ul#list li:last').find('input:item').val('');
```

to:

```
$('ul#list li:last').find('input').val('');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EwcjE/4/)**